# module jdk.compiler does not "opens com.sun.tools.javac.processing"

Tags: java, maven, openjdk-17

I get the following error if i execute mvn package

`module jdk.compiler does not "opens com.sun.tools.javac.processing" to unnamed module @15409d4e`

I use java 17

how can i fix this problem?

Comment: You use the latest version of Maven and the plugins in your pom.xml?

Comment: Also it would help to show the pom file etc. also the full log output ...

Comment: i have found the bug. i had updated lombok to latest version and it works now. so thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

it may be that the gradle version does not match and needs to be upgraded. For example, upgrade the grdle version to 7+